# send a folder from VNC host to USB hard disk

Tags: windows, vnc

I'm connected to a cluster using VNC and I would like to transfer a folder from the cluster to my PC running windows. In particular I would like to transfer it to the external hard disk connected to it. Is it possible?

Comment: You'll probably want to add a specific language tag so any solutions you get are relevant to you.

Comment: I don't think VNC provides any kind of file transfer capability, it's just for accessing the display. If you want to transfer files, use an application specific to that, such as `scp` or `ftp`.